# Gmail thread returned is 'undefined' on gmail just sent

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get a thread for an email just sent using the following:

```
var thread = GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, advancedArgs).search('subject:' + subject, 0, 1);
```

The first part sends an email and the second is trying to get the thread of the email with the same subject (which is unique!).

Nearly always the returned value for thread is 'undefined'. I suspect that this is a timing issue. Is there a possibility to ensure the message sent will be found for the thread to have a valid reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it related to time, you are making the search too fast. you could probably validate first if the search returns something and if not you can wait using `sleep(1000);` and then try again until you receive a good response.

Comment: Thanks! It works with the sleep. Unfortunately I am sending quite a few emails so I can not afford it. I'll have to split it up to 2 commands and perform them separately with sleep between sending the emails and tagging them.